# Deleting rows in PostgreSQL if column begins with a specific pattern

Tags: database, postgresql, reference, delete-row

I am very new at PostgreSQL and want to be able to delete rows from a table if a specific column starts with a certain pattern.

For example,

I have a `reference` column which is a sort of time stamp (YYMMDDHHMM). If the reference column starts with 16********, then i'd like it to be deleted.

So far, I know how to delete the column if the whole reference is known. E.g:

```
DELETE FROM my_tbl WHERE name='test1' AND ref_no=1601010000;
```

However, I need to change this so that the condition only specifies the first 2 digits of the reference number.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Read about `LIKE` operator: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html

Use this command to delete rows:

```
DELETE FROM my_tbl WHERE reference LIKE '16%'
```

---

Before deleting rows from the table, first check if a delete condition really works as expected using it in a regular SELECT statement:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE reference LIKE '16%'
```

---

If `reference` column is not of type `varchar` but for example `int`, you need first to conver (cast) it to a varchar datatype in this way:

```
SELECT * FROM my_tbl WHERE reference::varchar LIKE '16%'
DELETE FROM my_tbl WHERE reference::varchar LIKE '16%'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try the 'like' operator, it allows you to do pattern matching.

```
DELETE FROM my_tbl WHERE name LIKE '%test%';
```

The '%' character is a wildcard. The above line should delete every column where the name contains the string 'test'.

More info here: [pattern matching](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/8.3/static/functions-matching.html)